# Comparing 2 DoubleProperty to a value

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to compare a double property in an if statement but I cant get it right? any help?

```
private DoubleProperty choice=new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);        
if(choice==1)
    {
        System.out.print(to);
        pane.add(cost, 0, 7);
        pane.add(costlabel, 0, 10);;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(choice.get() == 1) {......}
```